# Using map with pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am writing a function that I would like to return a `pd.DataFrame()` and I would then like to use this function with `map`. I would then like to join these DataFrames to have one big DataFrame. Here's an example (note that this is not my problem I'm trying to solve, but just a toy problem):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x' : np.random.chisquare(df = 2, size = 10),
    'y' : np.random.chisquare(df = 5, size = 10)    
})

def z_score(x):
    z = (np.mean(df[x]) - df[x]) / np.std(df[x])
    mean_ctr = np.mean(df[x]) - df[x]
    out = pd.DataFrame({
        'z': z,
        'mean_ctr': mean_ctr,
        'var' : x
        })
    return out

list(map(z_score, ['x', 'y']))

pd.DataFrame(map(z_score, ['x', 'y']))  ## doesn't work
```

I can get my desired output if I run this function twice within `pd.concat()`

```
pd.concat([z_score('x'),
           z_score('y')])
```

Is this possible using the `map` function?

Comment: Perhaps you want `pd.concat([z_score(col) for col in ["x", "y"]])` ? Or `pd.concat([*map(z_score, ["x", "y"])])` but better use list-comprehension

Comment: what means `## doesn't work`? Do you get error message? Show it in question (not in comments). Do you get wrong result? Show example data, result which you get, and result which you expected.

Comment: using `map(z_score, ['x', 'y'])` you also run `z_score` twice.

Comment: the code should be using `concat()` since it retrieves the desired outcome in one line very nicely. Why complicate this ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely, Yes, I was looking for the list-comprehension approach.